How to create a zod tuple schema from zod object?
How can I define a Zod tuple schema from a zod object? I have a case that given a zod object I would need to create a generic schema builder that builds a new schema from the object keys and values/shapes. For example given object
const Test = z.object({
  first: z.string(),
  second: z.number(),
  third: z.object({
    something: z.string().array()
  })
})

I would need to create a schema like this:
const builder = <T extends z.AnyZodObject>(schema: T) => {
  const schemaObjectKeys = schema.keyof()
  const schemaShapes = schema.shape

  const newSchema = z.object({
    abc: z.tuple([z.object({ name: schemaObjectKeys }), schemaShapes[schemaObjectKeys]])
  })

  return newSchema
}

However this fails horribly. First of all the keys are of type z.ZodEnum<never>, but they probably should rather be z.ZodEnum<string>. Next issue is that how can I even map the keys and their keys to the tuple? The notation I have in the example does not work at all. Third, something more complex I would like to achieve, I would like to restrict the new schemas so that it is created only if the shape is certain shape. For example
const builder = <T extends z.AnyZodObject>(schema: T) => {
  const schemaObjectKeys = schema.keyof()
  const schemaShapes = schema.shape

  // create this only if the schemaShapes[schemaObjectKeys] equals to z.number()
  const newSchema = z.object({
    abc: z.tuple([z.object({ name: schemaObjectKeys }), schemaShapes[schemaObjectKeys]])
  })

  return newSchema
}

Is there a way to achieve this?
